# Sendgrid Unsub For Only Specified Group

Tags: sendgrid

I am using sendgrid unsub api's for who does not want the campaign e-mails.

But when I send request for unsub the email, the adress goes to global unsub list.

Here is my php code

```
$parameters = array(
        "api_user" => self::EMAIL_USER_NAME,
        "api_key"  => self::EMAIL_PASSWORD,
        "email"    => $email,
);

$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
```

How to specify an unsub group id for api call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the V2 API right now. Unsub groups are only available via the V3 API, using the [suppressions endpoint](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Suppression_Management/suppressions.html#-POST).

In V3, you POST addresses to the resource URL of the unsub group, for example, `https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/asm/groups/:group_id/suppressions`

Keep in mind that to use V3 you'll need to use the [updated authentication schema](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/index.html) that uses an `Authorization` header and a real API key.